# Examples of $C^*$-algebras in Noncommutative Geometry from A. Connes

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry

**Question**

I am working on $C^*$-algebras and I've been given Alain Connes's  book [Noncommutative Geometry](http://www.alainconnes.org/docs/book94bigpdf.pdf). I am having troubles with understanding the examples on pages 91-93 (86-88 in the printed book). Maybe the problem is, that I do not understand, how those algebras are constructed. Could somebody explain the second way of the construction (page 91 (85))? I am talking about the part starting:

2) The second is to consider the larger algebra $B \supset C(Y)$ of all $2 \times 2$ matrices:
$$
f =
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{aa} & f_{ab} \\
f_{ba} & f_{bb} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
...

I do not really understand, how to construct this matrix in general. For example - what is $f_{aa}, f_{ab},\ldots$? How are those constructed/represented e.g. in the example $2.\beta$ **The dual of the infinite dihedral group** (pages 92-93 (87-88))?

Many thanks.

**[Update 2]**

I have already asked this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1262207/112628) (about two days ago, without any answer yet), but maybe this site is more suitable for this type of question (although maybe only the same people will see it)? I am not sure, so I might delete one of them later (I really don't want to *spam* every question I don't get answered immediately.

**[Update]**

I would be glad to receive any tips or guesses. I am aware, that this is broad topic, I am not looking for precise and rigorous explanation.

Comment: I do understand the "put on hold".. However, I'll try to explain the process - firstly I've put this Q on math.stack and after two days without any answer (or comment) I have, based on this [answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/44/112628), decided to put the Q also here, and received good answer within an hour. I thought this question is about more advanced topics, although it includes _basic_ object (matrices, functions), it is directly taken from non-trivial book (at least from my point of view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it will help to see how the algebra $B$ is a special case of the general construction in $2.\alpha$.  The compact manifold is the space $Y = \{a, b\}$ consisting of two points.  The open cover of $Y$ consists of the sets $U_1 = \{a\}$ and $U_2 = \{b\}$.  The equivalence relation on $Y$ is just $a \sim a$, $b \sim b$, $a \sim b$, $b \sim a$, and thus its graph $\mathcal{R}$ in $Y \times Y$ is just $Y \times Y$ itself.

So let's build the C*-algebra $C^*(\mathcal{R})$ described in Proposition 1.  The underlying vector space is $C_0(\mathcal{R})$, and this is just:
$$C_0(\mathcal{R}) = C(\{a,a\}) \oplus C(\{a,b\}) \oplus C(\{b,a\}) \oplus C(\{b,b\})$$
Of course each algebra in the direct sum is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, so $C_0(\mathcal{R}) \cong \mathbb{C}^4$.  Still, let's label elements of $C(\{a,a\}) \cong \mathbb{C}$ as $f_{aa}$ (and similarly with the other summands) to keep track.  In other words, an element of $C_0(\mathcal{R}) \cong \mathbb{C}^4$ has the form $f = (f_{aa},f_{ab},f_{ba},f_{bb})$.

Now let's write out the product in $C^*(\mathcal{R})$ using the formula in Proposition 1:

$$fg(a,a) = \sum_{a \sim x \sim a} f(a,x)g(x,a) = f_{aa}g_{aa} + f_{ab}g_{ba}$$
$$fg(a,b) = \sum_{a \sim x \sim b} f(a,x)g(x,b) = f_{aa}g_{ab} + f_{ab}g_{bb}$$

and so on.  In other words, the product $fg$ is just the matrix product:

$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} f_{aa} & f_{ab} \\ f_{ba} & f_{bb} \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc} g_{aa} & g_{ab} \\ g_{ba} & g_{bb} \end{array}\right)$$

We find that $C^*(\mathcal{R})$ is isomorphic to the matrix algebra $M_2(\mathbb{C})$.  But certainly the construction is more interesting if the manifold and equivalence relation are not so trivial.

Comment: Thanks! This explains a lot. Few points: $f(x, y) \equiv f_{xy}$ right? Also the other equivalence on $Y, R = \{(a,a),(b,b)\}$ would give us isomorphism to $\{A \in M_2(\mathbb{C}), A \text{ diagonal}\}$, yes? In general $\operatorname{card}Y \neq 2$, would other sets, e.g. $Y_1 = \{a,b,c\}, Y_2 = \mathbb{N}$ lead to I assume isomorphism to $M_3(\mathbb{C}), M_\infty(\mathbb{C})$?

Comment: I think the last question depends, in 2.$\beta$ $Y= I_1 \cup I_2$, whether $Y$ is discrete or not. But thanks to you, I see, how 2.$\beta$ 2) is constructed, that is, we do this for each $t \in [0, 1]$, simplified. And exactly for the points $t \in \{0,1\}$ we get diagonal matrices, corresponding to $\{(t_i, t_i), i = 1,2\}$ (see my previous comment) and for the rest we get the general case, that is $\{(t_1, t_1), (t_1,t_2), (t_2,t_1), (t_2,t_2)\}$, where $t_i \in I_i$.

Comment: Many questions still arise - what is $C_0(X)$, resp. $C(X)$? I understand them as spaces of continuous functions vanishing at infinity, resp. only continuous functions? If so, are there any major consequences considering for example $C(R)$ instead of $C_0(R)$?

Comment: After few days I was going through this example again and I am not sure, it is right. $a\sim b$ iff $p(a) = p(b)$. So this example would work when $\operatorname{card}X = 1$ and $X$ is covered with two open sets $U_1=\{a\}, U_2 = \{b\}$ where $p(a) = p(b)$. Iff $X =\{a, b\}$ then such $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$ therefore there is nothing to identify.